# Как сделать так что-бы декоратор функции принимал пару аргументов?

Tags: javascript, функции, аргументы

```
Function.prototype.defer = function(ms){
  setTimeout(this, ms);
};

f.defer(1000)(1, 2);
```

Нужно чтобы декоратор принимал аргументы, которые находятся в разных скобках.

Answer (score 0):

Ну к примеру так. Верните функцию и далее вызовите её! Так же можете использовать стрелочную функцию чтобы не терять контекст:

```js
Function.prototype.defer = function(ms){
  /*setTimeout(this, ms);*/
  console.log('parent ms', ms)
  return (a, b) => {
    console.log('second params', a, b);
    console.log('child ms from parent', ms);
  };
};

Function.defer(1000)(1, 2);
```

Comment: Мне нужно передать аргументы a, b в другую функцию из декоратора Function.prototype.defer

Answer (score 0):

```
Function.prototype.defer = function(ms) {
  let f = this;
  return function(...args) {
    setTimeout(() => f.apply(this, args), ms);
  }
};
```